# Class not found error when trying to create an object

Tags: php

Instead of:

```
$price = "356";
$shipping = "0";
$total_price = $shipping + $price;

Price: <?php echo number_format((float)$price, 2, '.', ''); ?>
Shipping: <?php echo number_format((float)$shipping, 2, '.', ''); ?>
Total: <?php echo number_format((float)$total_price, 2, '.', ''); ?>
```

I want to use an object like this:

```
$price = "356";
$shipping = "0";
$total_price = $shipping + $price;

$oformat = new number_format(2, '.', '');

Price: <?= $oformat->format( (float) $price ); ?>
Shipping: <?= $oformat->format( (float) $shipping ); ?>
Total: <?= $oformat->format( (float) $total_price ); ?>
```

But I'm getting:

`Fatal error: Class 'number_format' not found in line...`

Why and how to do it properly?

Comment: number_format is a php function

Answer (score 0):

The class you want to use is called [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php). Here's an example:

```
<?php 
$price = 356.12;
$shipping = 12.24;
$total_price = $shipping + $price;
$oformat = new NumberFormatter('en_EN', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
?>
Price: <?= $oformat->format( $price ); ?>
<br/>
Shipping: <?= $oformat->format( $shipping ); ?>
<br/>
Total: <?= $oformat->format( $total_price); ?>
```

If you don't have NumberFormatter available you can create your own class:

```
<?php
class MyNumberFormatter
{
    public function format($valueToFormat)
    {
        return number_format( $valueToFormat , 2, '.', '');
    }
}
$price = 356.12;
$shipping = 12.24;
$total_price = $shipping + $price;
$oformat = new MyNumberFormatter();
?>
Price: <?= $oformat->format( $price ); ?>
<br/>
Shipping: <?= $oformat->format( $shipping ); ?>
<br/>
Total: <?= $oformat->format( $total_price); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow next steps :

1. Go to the "www" folder inside wamp folder.
2. Create a text file and name it "format.php".
3. Copy-paste next code :

> ```
> <?php
> class format {
> public function number_format ( $num , $dec, $sep ) {
> // ADD YOUR CODE HERE.
> return $num;
> }
> }
> ?>
> ```

4. Create another text file and name it "main.php".
5. Copy-paste next code :

> ```
> < ? php
> require_once( "format.php" ); // IMPORT CLASS.
> $fmt = new format(); // CREATE OBJECT OF YOUR CLASS.
>
> $price = 356;
> $shipping = 0;
> $total_price = $shipping + $price;
> ?>
> Price : <?php echo $fmt->number_format( $price,2,"." ); ?>
> <br/>
> Shipping : <?php echo $fmt->number_format( $shipping,2,"." ); ?>
> <br/>
> Total price : <?php echo $fmt->number_format( $total_price,2,"." ); ?>
> ```

6. Start wamp server (green icon on the bottom right of your screen).
7. Open any browser and type next line in the address bar :

   http://localhost:8099/main.php

Explanation : you create a class in a separated file ("format.php"), then you create an instance of your class in order to call its methods ("number_format"). In a separated file is better because you can re-use that code.